# (J)Ruby - safe way to redefine core classes?

Tags: ruby, security, jruby

What is the safe way to redefine methods in core classes like File, String etc. I'm looking for implementing something similar to the Java Security Manager in (J)Ruby.

I'm looking for a way to redefine a method by first seeing which class/script has called this method and if that class/script belong to a list of some blacklisted classes (that I keep track of) I want to raise an exception, If the calling class belong to a non-blacklisted class then allow the operation. something like:

```
class String
  alias_method :old_length, :length

  def length
    if(#nowHowDoIGetTheCallingClass)
      raise "bad boy"
    else
      old_length
  end
end
```

I tried this in JRuby, but this works only alternatively. One time the new length method is called and next time the old length method is called. I guess the `alias` doesn't work properly in JRuby! >.<

Answer (score 0):

If something works sometimes, but not at other times, it's more likely to be your code that's the problem, not JRuby. [Select isn't broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/a-pragmatic-quick-reference.html)

Comment: It's strange that it's works `exactly` alternatively. I'm trying to fix it for the past 2 days. Anyway, thanks for the link. Nice read! ^^